# How to take count of individual users from a database?

Tags: python

I have a table in postgresql database that contain 9 rows. there is a row named 'username' and a row named 'user_id' near it also 'status_id'. In the username row there are several names. Names get repeated several times. the sample of the 3 rows are given below:

```
username  user1_id   status_id
--------  --------   ---------
  ali        2          1
  pam        3          1
  pam        3          2
  ali        2          1
  ali        2          2
  pam        3          2
   .         .          .
   .         .          .
  goes-on    goes-on
```

the above is an example. in the above case there are only 2 usernames "ali and pam". In my case there are 14 usernames with specified user1_id's. what i want to do is to get the user count, which means i want to get the count of how many times ali come in status_id 1 and status_id 2 individually. Same condition for pam. how can i do this in python?

```
Expected result:
ali(1) = 2
ali(2) = 1
pam(1) = 1
pam(2) = 2
```

values inside the () is status_id

Comment: you need to group by  'user_id' and 'status_id' and count unique values

Comment: @ahmed actually I have few users, I just used ali and pam as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followingly way you can use groupby to get your desire output. Where you need to groupby on two columns `username`, `status_id` and count the `user1_ids`.

Code:

```
df = df.groupby(['status_id','username'], as_index=False)['user1_id'].count()
df.apply(lambda x: '{}({})={}'.format(x.username, x.status_id,x.user1_id) , axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    ali(1)=1
1    pam(1)=1
2    ali(2)=1
3    pam(2)=1
```

Comment: Yes this code works fine. thanks for your help. I did it in a different way without using pandas